# How can I use display different content based on the results of get_permalink() value

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce0uA.jpg)  I'm new to WordPress and I'd like to play around with the child theme templates. I have 3 different blog posts on the Blog page and I would like to display a custom widget under the excerpt section for each blog post based on their permalink.

I'm thinking of using the **get_permalink()** function in conjunction with an if statement but I'm not sure how to write the if statement to do this. Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Can you post the template file that you're using? That will help us help you. :)

Comment: What you need is function `is_single();` with an `if statement`. You can query slugs, id's Have a look to the wp reference 

 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses and apologies for my late reply. @JoelHager I'm using the Basel theme from Theme Forrest.